# Stuck on Ubuntu boot screen clean install

Tags: boot, graphics, dell

I'm a new user of Linux. I made a clean install of Ubuntu 12.04 LTS in my notebook Dell Inspiron N4010.

The intallation went ok, but after restarting it got stuck on the purple screen with the logo.

I've read it may be a graphic card problem, but I don't know how to solve it.

When I press <kbd>Esc</kbd> during the boot, this is the messaage:

```
fsck de util-linux 2.20.1

fsck de util-linux 2.20.1

/dev/sda1: clean 156852/2809856 files, 898520/11230208 blocks

/dev/sda2: clean 20/27457776 files, 1774771/109863168 blocks

Skipping profile in /etc/apparmor.d/disable: usr.bin.firefox

Skipping profile in /etc/apparmor.d/disable: usr.sbin.rsysloyd

*Starting mDNS/DNS-SD daemon  (OK)

*Starting AppArmor profiles   (OK)

*Starting bluetooh daemon     (OK)

*Starting network connection manager (OK)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [My computer boots to a black screen, what options do I have to fix it?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it)